# Website suddenly stopped loading due to php include?

Tags: include, typeerror

I was working on my website when suddenly it wouldn't load anymore. After investigating i found out that this no longer worked:

```
<?php include 'core/init.php'; ?>
```

But when i changed it to this:

```
<?php include '/core/init.php'; ?>
```

Those includes are at the top of my index.php so the page would load nothing. It worked fine, although none of my links no longer worked, it gave me internal 500 error.

Investigating further i got these errors from safari console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal   Server Error) (localhost, line 0)
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.hide()')
close (content_start_0.js, line 1)
```

I've been working on my site for the past month using:

```
<?php include 'core/init.php'; ?>
```

and never had a problem until a few moments ago.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did the file `core/init.php` change?

Comment: The file itself did not change locations. There is another include in the init file that changed. It was a functions file that is called at the top of the init file

Comment: see if there are syntax errors or some kind of errors in that file

Comment: It happened because i changed a function name inside the functions file. I don't know why it would make a big deal for me to change a functions name. But I am still getting that second error in safari even though the page loads fine now, any ideas on that second error?

Comment: It is evaluating a javascript function to undefined. Most likely, it is not resolving `this` due to scoping issues

Comment: How would i fix that?

Comment: :) again goes back to what has changed :). Well revert it to the last known working condition and see what has changed

Comment: I'll check it out. The error does not show up in google chrome

Answer (score 3):

The second error is caused by the Firebug Lite extension for Safari.

Go to your inspector, click resources, then expand Extension Scripts. There should be a file there named content_start_0.js.

You can make the error go away if you go into Preferences for Safari, click the Extensions tab, then uncheck "Enable Firebug Lite for Safari."

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me resolve this long standing problem I had.